# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..39: 42 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this is a common issue when we are not using the `itemCount` to list view. but here is my code

```
ListView.separated(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              print('num : ${episode[index]!.episodeNum.toString()}');
              final data = episode[index];
              if (type == adminPanel) {
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    EpisodeBar(
                      episode: index + 1,
                      caption: data!.caption,
                      time: data.time,
                      colorTheme: AppThemeColors.colorList[index],
                      duration: data.time,
                      link: data.link,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        EditButton(data: data, courseID: crsId),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        DeleteButton(eps: _eps, data: data, courseID: crsId),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
              log('${snapshot.data!.length}');
              return EpisodeBar(
                episode: data!.episodeNum.toString(),
                caption: data.caption,
                time: data.time,
                colorTheme: AppThemeColors.colorList[index],
                duration: data.time,
                link: data.link,
              );
            },
            itemCount:snapshot.data!.length,
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              if (type == adminPanel) {
                return const Divider(
                  thickness: 1,
                  height: 40,
                );
              }
              return const SizedBox(height: 20);
            },
          );
```

here is what's happening

[image]

I did use the item count, and everything was working properly,
until the 40th list. and when I added the new data as 41, it shows this error, I couldn't find any mistake on this code. and why did exactly this stop working on 41??

Comment: where exactly does the error point? when you click on the associated cause line in your log

Answer (score 0):

Such errors are usually caused by indexing values before they are rendered!(My thought)

So to solve this, do this:

```
ListView.separated(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              //print('num : ${episode[index]!.episodeNum.toString()}'); // simply remove this
              final data = episode[index]; 
              if (type == adminPanel) {
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    EpisodeBar(
                      episode: index + 1,
                      caption: data!.caption,
                      time: data.time,
                      colorTheme: AppThemeColors.colorList[index],
                      duration: data.time,
                      link: data.link,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        EditButton(data: data, courseID: crsId),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        DeleteButton(eps: _eps, data: data, courseID: crsId),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
              log('${snapshot.data!.length}');
              return EpisodeBar(
                episode: data!.episodeNum.toString(),
                caption: data.caption,
                time: data.time,
                colorTheme: AppThemeColors.colorList[index],
                duration: data.time,
                link: data.link,
              );
            },
            itemCount:snapshot.data!.length,
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              if (type == adminPanel) {
                return const Divider(
                  thickness: 1,
                  height: 40,
                );
              }
              return const SizedBox(height: 20);
            },
          );
```

Comment: still showing the error :(

Answer (score 0):

Here should be the problem:

```
final data = episode[index];
```

There's a chance that the `episode` array haven't the following `index` position.

Try to verify if they have the same element quantity.

---

To verify, **and only verify**, try this before build the ListView:

```
if (episode.length != snapshot.data!.length) {
    log('episode length is different from snapshot length');
    
    log('episode: ${episode.length}');
    log('snapshot: ${snapshot.data!.length}');

    return Container();
}
```

Comment: it didn't print anything. so episode length is not different from snapshot length. then what's the problem??

Comment: Try it: `itemCount: episode.length`

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: I recommend rebuild the widget step by step to find the error. Probably  is not the widget, but the error may be in what generates the result for the itemCount.

Comment: i found the error, it wasn't the widget's mistake as you said

Comment: Happy that you found the error :)